# Installing Upstart stops autologin from working

Tags: raspbian, boot

I have set up autologin by editing `/etc/inittab`, changing the line

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1
```

to

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --autologin pi --noclear 38400 tty1
```

This works fine. I have now installed Upstart to run and respawn some Python scripts on boot, however the device no longer boots to the terminal screen but instead prompts for a username/password.

I'm using the `2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img` image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upstart replaces the traditionally init system, which means that the `/etc/inittab` file is now [effectively ignored](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Technical_Notes/deployment.html), ignoring your change. All is not lost. Upstart also allows automatic logins. It's simply a matter of working out which configuration file. Information on this seems to be a bit sketchy (and I don't have an Upstart enabled system to test with), but it [looks](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Frontend_Auto_Login#UpStart) [like](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1185270) you can edit the `/etc/init/tty1.conf` file to add the `--autologin pi` bit, so you end up with something like this in the file:

```
exec /sbin/getty --autologin pi --noclear 38400 tty1
```